# Making RGB image using FITS files with different dimensions

Tags: fits, color

I want to make an RGB image using 3 FITS files: one IR image from *Spitzer* and the other two from *UVIT*. I tried to make them using **make_lupton_rgb** in *Astropy*, but it doesn't work in the case of FITS files with unequal dimensions. I tried to use DS9, but I cannot export the resultant RGB image due to different dimensions. How do I get around this?

````
hdu1 = fits.open('fuv_.fits')
fdata = hdu1[0].data
w1 = wcs.WCS(hdu1[0].header)
    
hdu2 = fits.open('nuvcrop.fits')
ndata = hdu2[0].data
w2 = wcs.WCS(hdu2[0].header)

hdu3=fits.open('_IRAC_3.6.fits')
datat = hdu3[0].data

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40, 40))
ax = plt.subplot(projection=w2)

rgb_default = make_lupton_rgb(0.5*ndata, 0.5*ndata,3*fdata)#, filename="qw.jpeg")
plt.imshow(datat, origin='lower')
```
````

Comment: An RGB image consists of three values _per pixel_, so your three images need some values for these pixels. Unless I misunderstand, isn't it just a question of interpolating your three images to a common grid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [reproject](https://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package to interpolate two of the fits files onto the WCS of the third file.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import astropy.visualization
import reproject

fdata hdu1[0].data

ndata, _ = reproject.reproject_interp(hdu2[0], hdu1[0].header)

datat, _ = reproject.reproject_interp(hdu3[0], hdu1[0].header)

image_rgb = astropy.visualization.make_lupton_rgb(fdata, ndata, datat, filename="qw.jpeg)
```

This is just an example, make sure to choose to interpolate onto the coordinate system of whatever image you desire.