# Crop a FITS file in shape of another

Tags: astrophysics, astropy, fits

I have a FITS file, let us say file A. I have another FITS file, file B. File B has a smaller footprint than file A. I want to crop file A in shape of file B. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Do both files have the same pixel scale?

Comment: No. They are of different pixel scales.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to use the [reproject package](https://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#) which I showed you how to use in a [previous answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/51772/35318) to a question you asked. Does that help?